# Disabling the PostgreSQL 8.4 tsvector parser's `file` token type

Tags: postgresql, parsing, tsvector

I have some documents that contain sequences such as `radio/tested` that I would like to return hits in queries like

```
select * from doc
where to_tsvector('english',body) @@ to_tsvector('english','radio')
```

Unfortunately, the default parser takes `radio/tested` as a `file` token (despite being in a Windows environment), so it doesn't match the above query.  When I run `ts_debug` on it, that's when I see that it's being recognized as a file, and the lexeme ends up being `radio/tested` rather than the two lexemes `radio` and `test`.

Is there any way to configure the parser not to look for `file` tokens?  I tried

```
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.english
    DROP MAPPING FOR file;
```

...but it didn't change the output of `ts_debug`.  If there's some way of disabling `file`, or at least having it recognize both `file` and all the words that it thinks make up the directory names along the way, or if there's a way to get it to treat slashes as hyphens or spaces (without the performance hit of `regexp_replace`ing them myself) that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the only way to do what you want is to create your own parser :-(  Copy wparser_def.c to a new file, remove from the parse tables (`actionTPS_Base` and the ones following it) the entries that relate to files (`TPS_InFileFirst`, `TPS_InFileNext` etc), and you should be set.  I think the main difficulty is making the module conform to PostgreSQL's C idiom (`PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1` and so on).  Have a look at `contrib/test_parser/` for an example.

Comment: Oh gosh...that's unfortunate.  Thanks for answering and for the tips, I'm glad to know what it involves.